# Etymology of крест

Tags: этимология, лексикон

[Russian wiktionary](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82) claim that the word крест is loanword from Old High German krist. Is it traditional and valid etymology? Do Russian have any trace of proper (not borrowed) Protoslavic word with meaning of крест?
The evolution of meaning cited in wiktionary is very "strange" for me also: Jesus Christ > crucifixion > cross. Russian language (Proto-Slavic) have had no word for very simple "cross"?!

**EDIT**: I asked the question not clear enough actually:
1) Why the evolution of semantics of Proto-Slavic(sic!) word *krьstъ start by meaning Jesus Christ, clearly Proto-Slavic (circa 7th to 8th centuries AD) was far before history of Christianity. How this meaning could be in Proto-Slavic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-borrowed Slavic word is ***пересечение***.

In PIE a crossover apparently was called ***pertus***.

Comment: Side note: **Пересечение**, just like English **intersection**, has a notion of cutting. **Крест**, **крестовина** are not necessarily made by cutting out.

Comment: @Anixx Thank you for not borrowed word in Russian. But the evolution of meaning of this word is still dubious for me. Do linguists any explanation on this evolution rather than the reconstructions of Vasmer?

Answer (score 1):

The same etymology of word "крест" is supported by etymological dictionary by [Vasmer](http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-6126.htm)

> *Крест* was borrowed from Church Slavic.  Old Russian *крьстъ* was used in a treaty between Prince Igor and Byzantian Greece in 911 (that was before Kievan Rus adopted Christianity)
>
> Originally **krьstъ* meant Christ and it was derived Old German krist, christ

I am not aware of another word with the meaning of *cross* that would indicate/suggest Protoslavic origin.

Comment: I think he was Vasmer since he was a German working in Nazi Germany.

Answer (score 1):

Native Russian words similar to **cross** are **поперёк** (adv., prep.) and **поперечный** (adj.). But the corresponding verb is rarely used in everyday speech: **перечить** - **to cross/contradict someone**. And the nouns **поперечина** and **поперечник** also have limited usage. Thus, in everyday speech we usually choose verbs and nouns starting with `пере-` or `против-`, if we need to say something 'cross-related'.

Comment: I'm not sure that Russian поперёк mean cross. I think it only mean "from side to other", antonym of **lengthwise**. Russian поперёк don't have notion of intersection or crossing, like two pieces crossing each other. In поперёк и поперечина are only one piece.

Comment: Well, the difference is quite little. Being `anti-lengthwise` implies `crossing something` anyway. So the dictionaries usually translate `поперёк` as `across` and vice versa. While `пересечение` is literally the same as `intersection`.